# Postfix mysql different schemas and test user

Tags: mysql, postfix-mta

I am trying to setup postfix mail server using ansible playbook. I am puzzled to understand different ways to setup postfix with mysql. I am not able to hold on to a complete schema. The one I [got here](https://github.com/gjuric/ansible-mailserver/blob/master/roles/mail/files/postfix.sql) and [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-postfix-dovecot-mysql-centos4.5)
are some examples.

Using the schema from ansible role above I have setup postfix. And the schema tables include:

```
show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_mail    |
+-------------------+
| alias             |
| alias_destination |
| domain            |
| domain_users      |
| mailbox           |
| mailbox_usage     |
| user              |
+-------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I want to [test](http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/8/6/postfix-using-telnet-to-test-postfix) the postfix server with a test user /mailbox and domain.So I am looking for a way to init the schema for a test user. Any kind of help is appreciated

**Edit**
Tried to add a test user:

```
mysql> select * from user;
+----+-----------+---------------+--------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | username  | password      | active | super_admin | created_at          | modified_at         |
+----+-----------+---------------+--------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | sakhunzai | dTzdFMm0DSvmM |      1 |           0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+-----------+---------------+--------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from domain;
+-------------+--------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| name        | active | backup_mx | default_mailbox_quota | created_at          | modified_at         |
+-------------+--------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| example.com |      1 |         0 |            1073741824 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+-------------+--------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mailbox;
+-----------+-------------+------------+------+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| username  | domain      | local_part | name | active | quota_mbytes | quota_messages | created_at          | modified_at         | password      |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| sakhunzai | example.com |            | NULL |      1 |            0 |              0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | wZQ9cRLxshVEY |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Testing from telnet:

```
telnet mail.example.com 25
Trying 127.0.1.1...
Connected to mail.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.com ESMTP Postfix
HELO test.example.com
250 mail.example.com
MAIL FROM: <sakhunzai@example.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<sakhunzai@example.com>
550 5.1.1 <sakhunzai@example.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table
```

**Edit 2**
After updating username I am able to complete the test:

```
update user set username="sakhunzai@example.com";
update mailbox set username="sakhunzai@example.com";

telnet mail.example.com 25
Trying 127.0.1.1...
Connected to mail.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.com ESMTP Postfix
HELO test.example.com
250 mail.example.com
MAIL FROM: <sakhunzai@example.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<sakhunzai@example.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Subject: test message
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3BEEB40940
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But with some errors in mail.log file:
 `to=<sakhunzai@example.com>, relay=none, delay=44, delays=44/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)`

```
Nov 10 08:13:51  postfix/smtpd[32013]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 10 08:14:09  postfix/smtpd[32013]: 3BEEB40940: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 10 08:14:49  postfix/cleanup[32020]: 3BEEB40940: message-id=<20151110081409.3BEEB40940@mail.example.com>
Nov 10 08:14:49  postfix/qmgr[8096]: 3BEEB40940: from=<sakhunzai@example.com>, size=337, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 10 08:14:49  postfix/qmgr[8096]: warning: connect to transport private/smtp-amavis: No such file or directory
Nov 10 08:14:49  postfix/error[32021]: 3BEEB40940: to=<sakhunzai@example.com>, relay=none, delay=44, delays=44/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
Nov 10 08:14:56  postfix/smtpd[32013]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
delay_warning_time = 4h
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 51200000
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks.regexp
mydestination =
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domains_maps.cf
relayhost =
smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks.pcre
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination reject_unlisted_recipient reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/private/mail.example.com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mail.example.com.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_mailbox_maps.cf proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
   -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
   -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
# Coment the above line if you do not want to sign localy originated mail from the pickup service
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
#uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
#ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
#bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
#scalemail-backend unix -   n   n   -   2   pipe
#  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
#mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
#  ${nexthop} ${user}

# Dovecot
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${domain} -m ${extension}

# Amavisd-new
smtp-amavis     unix    -       -       -       -       2       smtp
   -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
   -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
   -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
   -o max_use=20

127.0.0.1:10025 inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
   -o content_filter=
   -o local_recipient_maps=
   -o relay_recipient_maps=
   -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
   -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
   -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
   -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
   -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
   -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
   -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
   -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
   -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
   -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
   -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
   -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
   -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
   -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
   -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings
```

Comment: Have you setup main.cf?

Comment: What are your Virtual user mappings?

Comment: yes everything , as defined in ansible role https://github.com/gjuric/ansible-mailserver/blob/master/roles/mail/templates/postfix/main.cf.j2

Comment: please check my test data in edits

Comment: Show me postfix configuration, specially for local_recipient_maps

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam , please check Edit 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94781/discussion-between-muhammad-muazzam-and-sakhunzai).

Answer (score 0):

Based upon [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/mail-transport-unavailable-error-753514/) and [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/postfix-mail-transport-unavailable.52908/) similar issues:

Comment this line

```
-o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
```

and try

Comment: Muhammad, thanks , I managed to fix the queue issue after fixing port to -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

Comment: I think that was 'default listening socket' `10026` vs `10024` which was defined in main.cf

Comment: amavisd acts similar to a mailserver, just that it listens only on localhost with IP 10024. If a mail is received by postfix and the postfix configuration redirected the email to this "internal" mailserver on port 10024, then a postqueue -f will just try to redeliver the emails to amavisd as amavisd is stored as next step for email processing in the mail inside the mailqueue while a full requeue will tell postfix to act as if the email is received again so that it decides again where to deliver the email.